# Trying to remove all unlicensed users from the Global address list using Powershell

Tags: powershell, office365

I'm trying to remove all users that are unlicensed from the global address list.

So far, I've found that ...

`$mboxes = Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly`

... will get me all unlicensed users, and put them in a variable called `$mboxes`, however there doesn't appear to be an Identity here.

For when I try and run something like:

`foreach ($mbox in $mboxes) { Set-Mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -Identity $mbox }`

I get back the following error.

`Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Identity'.`

I've tried exporting that data to a CSV and creating an "Identity" header, however I get the same issue after re-importing the data back into PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution was very close.
From the `Set-Mail` docs:

> The `-Identity` parameter specifies the mailbox that you want to
>   modify. You can use any value that uniquely identifies the mailbox.

Use `$mbox.UserPrincipalName` to pass the User Principal Name.

```
$mboxes = Get-MsolUser -All -UnlicensedUsersOnly
foreach ($mbox in $mboxes) { Set-Mailbox -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $true -Identity $mbox.UserPrincipalName }
```

Comment: Wow, so close, really appreciate the feedback. That certainly did the trick!